# How to Create a Lead from a Contact

Tags: apex

I want to build a trigger that will create a lead object from a contact object if the contact meets certain criteria. So far, I have:

```
trigger CreateLead on Contact (after update) {
    List<Contact> cont = new List<Contact>();
    for (integer i=0; i < trigger.new.size(); i++) {
        cont.add(newLead = new Lead (
            lead.LeadSource = "Sales Development - Inbound",
            lead.Lead_Source_Details__c = "Auto: Potential High Volume")
            *Other Lead Fields Here*
        );
    }
insert cont;
}
```

Where do I insert the conditional statements? For example, I want to create a Lead from the Contact if the [Contact].Account.NumberOfEmployees >= 100.

> Thank you for your help! Can someone give this a once-over?

```
trigger CreateLead on Contact (after update) {
List<Lead> lstLead = new List<Lead>();
for (integer i=0; i < trigger.new.size(); i++) {
    Contact con = trigger.new[i];

    if(con.Account.Primary_Team__c="Sales"
        & con.Account.New_or_Existing_Account__c="New"
        & (con.Account.NumberOfEmployees>=100
            OR con.Account.website != ""
            OR (con.Account.Estimated_Reports_Volume__c != "1-5 reports/month"
                & con.Accounts.Estimated_Reports_Volume__c != ""))
        )
    {
        lstLead.add(newLead = new Lead (
            lead.LeadSource = "Sales Development - Inbound",
            lead.Lead_Source_Details__c = "Auto: Potential High Volume",
            lead.FfirstName = con.FirstName,
            lead.LastName = con.LastName,
            lead.Company = con.Account.Name,
            lead.Email = con.Email,
            lead.Phone = con.Account.Phone,
            lead.Website = con.Account.Website,
            lead.Originating_Storm_ID__c = con.Account.Storm_ID__c,
            lead.Owner = "005F0000004Aboz",
            lead.Related_Account__c = con.AccountID,
            lead.SD_Rep__c = "Andy",
            lead.Status = "Open")
        );
    }
}
if(!lstLead.isEmpty()) {
    insert lstLead;
}
}
```

Reason we are using a Lead from a Contact is to basically create an auto inbound lead gen pool for our SD to qualify.

Comment: Two things. 1) You are adding records of type `Lead` to a list of type `Contact`. This code should not compile. 2) This is a good use case for Process Builder.

Comment: Process builder is much better for this, as adrian larson pointed out.   No code and no tests, and is intuititive.

Answer (score 2):

Why you want to create Lead from Contact ? Shouldn't Lead created first and then Contact ?

To answer your question, you can use code something like below :

```
trigger CreateLead on Contact (after update) {
    List<Lead> lstLead = new List<Lead>();
    for (integer i=0; i < trigger.new.size(); i++) {
        Contact con = trigger.new[i];

        if(con.Account.NumberOfEmployees >= 100)
        {
            lstLead.add(newLead = new Lead (
                lead.LeadSource = "Sales Development - Inbound",
                lead.Lead_Source_Details__c = "Auto: Potential High Volume")
                *Other Lead Fields Here*
            );
        }

    }
    if(!lstLead.isEmpty())
    {
        insert lstLead;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below,

```
 trigger CreateLead on Contact (after update) {
    List<Lead> leadList = new List<Lead>();
    List<Contact> contList = [Select Id,Name,otherFields, Account.NumberOfEmployees From contact where id =: trigger.new];
    for (integer i=0; i < contList.size(); i++) {
        if(contList[i].Account.NumberOfEmployees){
            leadList.add(new Lead (
                lead.LeadSource = "Sales Development - Inbound",
                lead.Lead_Source_Details__c = "Auto: Potential High Volume")
            );
        }
    }
insert leadList;
}
```

This does not consider existing leads. Everytime contact is updated, it will create new leads. You will need to check for existing leads. If it there already, probably do not create another one.

Since "NumberOfEmployees" is not a field in contact, you need to query it separately. It will not be available in trigger.new.